# VB: Return a pdf without create

Tags: vb.net

I'm developing a MVC web app in VB.Net and I have a pdf in base64 string format. It's possible to return that pdf to the view and see it, without creating a temp.pdf file?

Comment: "the view" - what is "the view"? What *type* of application are you writing? Is this a windows forms application? WPF? Windows Store? Some form of ASP.Net?

Comment: I'm developing a MVC web app in VB.Net and i want to return a pdf.

Something simiñar to this but without create:

   Return File(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\file.pdf", "application/pdf")

Comment: You can write to a response stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say in a comment that you want something like:

```
Return File(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\file.pdf", "application/pdf")
```

So why not simply:

```
Return File(Convert.FromBase64String(base64string),"application/pdf")
```

References:

[`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.convert.frombase64string)
[`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460208%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)